# Placing points on a curve generated using PGF plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using methods like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39421/412) (and with more details [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33610/412)) can be useful when one tries to draw *"free"* curves. However, once a free curve is obtained it can be very useful to access arbitrary points on it. Unfortunately, the following naive approach is useless:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

  \draw[thick,mark=ball] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(1,1) (1.4,0.5) (0.4,-0.2) (0.6,-0.2) (0.2,-1.4) (-0.5,-1.1) (-1,-1.6) (-1.4,0.4)}
  node[pos=0.5]{A} node[pos=0.9]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

since it yields the following:

[image]

So what is the right way to specify points on a curve generated as above?

Comment: I think you can get some insights from [TikZ: using the pos = x in a node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128579/13304).

Comment: You can use the markings decoration to have periodic marks

Comment: The main problem is (as always) the `smooth` option. It has so many interferences with other options. For further info you might want to have a look at my answer to [Add arrows to a smooth tikz function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163689/add-arrows-to-a-smooth-tikz-function/163695#163695).